# Can I use named parameters with jOOQ SQL executor?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

I am using jOOQ to execute arbitrary SQL queries. I am doing this as following:

```
String result = create.fetchSingle("SELECT ...").getValue(0, String.class);
```

This query always returns one row and one column, hence the usage of `fetchSingle` and `getValue(0, T)`. I could not find a method which combines the two.

I now want to pass a named parameter to that query. The parameter is used at several places, so I thought using a named parameter was a good usage here. The type of this parameter is an array of strings.

How can I do this? How do I refer to that parameter in the query? In JDBC, I would write `:name_of_parameter::text[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you're looking for is [`DSLContext.fetchSingle(String, Object...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchSingle-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), which accepts a SQL string with parameter placeholders, as well as the actual bindings.

However, it does not support named parameters, only indexed parameters, so you'll have to repeat the value several times, e.g.

```
create.fetchSingle("SELECT 'a' WHERE ?::text[] = ?::text[]", value, value)
      .getValue(0, String.class);
```

Comment: @JellyOrns: Yes indeed. There are a few feature requests on the roadmap to support them more thoroughly. They are supported, but not in the plain SQL API

Comment: Lukas, that's good to hear. I'll keep an eye on the changelog of future versions!